# Unable to get browser when using Protractor with IE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm running tests on Protractor that run just ok on Chrome but fail on IE 11. I get this error:

> [internet explorer #1]     Failed: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information)

IE does navigate to the Angular app I want to test. It just cannot do anything else stated in the test it block. It just outputs that error on console and Protractor can't even close the window.

My protractor conf:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs : [ '../specs/**/*.protractorspec.js' ],
    multiCapabilities: [{
          'browserName': 'internet explorer',
          'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true
        }, {
          'browserName': 'chrome'
        }]
};
```

And my test:

```
describe('Tick Tack Toe game', function() { 
  it('marks positions as played', function() {
    browser.get('http://192.168.14.59/protractor/ticktacktoe.html');
    var p1name = element(by.id("p1nameText"));
    p1name.clear();
    p1name.sendKeys('Pedro');
    var p1filtered = element(by.id('p1filtered'));
    expect(p1filtered.getText()).toEqual('el tal Pedro');
  });
});
```

Some forums and questions here in SO got me [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) where I read (scroll to Required Configuration) that I might need to create a registry key because of the version of IE (11). I did it and did not work. I'm sure my machine is 64 bits so I followed those instructions. Also tried creating a QWORD instead of the mentioned DWORD and didn't work either.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: What if you comment out the `ignoreProtectedModeSettings` line? Also what if you move the `browser.get()` call to `beforeEach()`? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe funny thing: IE passes running every test instruction abnormally slow. It types my name like P (3 secs) e (3 secs) and so on... And Chrome fails. It closes abruptly.

Comment: Don't use the 64-bit `IEDriverServer.exe`. Use the 32-bit one instead. Technical reasons why are outlined [here](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2014/09/screenshots-sendkeys-and-sixty-four.html). Also, as @alecxe said, don't set `ignoreProtectedModeSettings`. Technical reasons why are discussed [here](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html).

Comment: @JimEvans well post it as an answer 'cause it worked :)